# Conditional Density $\Pr(X>2\mid Y<4)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(x,y) = e^{-y}$ be the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$, with $0<x<y<\infty$.

Prove that $\Pr(X>2 \mid Y<4)=0.0885$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** After sketching the region in question, you should be able to set up the integrals as follows:
$$
\Pr(X > 2 \mid Y < 4) = \frac{\int_2^4 \int_x^4 e^{-y} ~dy~ dx}{\int_0^4 \int_x^4 e^{-y} ~ dy ~ dx}
$$